# Issues in Fedora detecting on board NIC card

Tags: linux

Basically I have two NIC cards (on-board + Added in PCI slot) on my Linux machine running Fedora 12.By default the OS detects the NIC card in the PCI slot but it fails to detect the on board network card.Following are few details of the same

> Linux Vivek 2.6.32.26-175.fc12.i686.PAE #1 SMP Wed Dec 1 21:45:50 UTC 2010 i686 i686 i386 
>   GNU/Linux

ifconfig -a doesen't show the on board NIC card.Any thoughts for it please?

Since it is also related to network configuration. I posted it here.

Comment: can you post the output of `lspci` ?

Comment: Please post the output of `lspci -nn`.

Comment: 00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1502] (rev 04)                                            05:02.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6105/VT6106S [Rhine-III] [1106:3106] (rev 8b)

Comment: In this Ethernet controller of VIA Technologies is being detected. I am wondering why the other ethernet controller is listed among PCI buses

Answer (score 1):

Your Fedora is too old and the Intel Network controller in question seem to be Intel® 82579LM Gigabit Ethernet Controller.

Couple of options, check

```
$ sudo lsmod | grep e1000
$ sudo modprobe e1000
$ sudo dmesg | grep e1000
```

You can compile and install the latest e1000 driver from here -- http://sourceforge.net/projects/e1000/

Or, upgrade/re-install your fedora to the latest version of 17.

Answer (score 1):

The base problem is the Fedora-12 didn't have the suitable e1000 drivers as chida described above.Here is the working solution.

(1) [Suitable drivers can be found here.](http://www.intel.com/support/ethernetcomponents/controllers/82579/sb/CS-032239.htm)

(2) Follow the instructions in README to build the sources.

(3) You will find the `.ko` object in `/lib/modules/<KERNEL VERSION>/kernel/drivers/net/e1000e/e1000e.[k]o`

(4) `insmod` of the above kernel object should bring the NIC up.